# Salesforce Console - Open CTI Integration

Tags: visualforce, cti

We are in the process of integrating Open CTI with salesforce console. My requirement is to search for a record based on the incoming phone# and If it exists then popup on the console OR create the record then popup.

Gone through the console API guide. Not sure how to really capture events. I thought of beginning with **fireOnCallBegin()** event. But not sure where to put a visualforce page(I meant as a side bar component or somewhere) that listens for events and popup new tabs or open existing tabs. In My opinion, the page that is listening for events should not be visible to users and it should sit in the background and listen for events.

Anyway would you give me some input where to begin based on my requirements. Thanks and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your objects which you want to search in "Call center Settings" and use Open CTI API to the search. That should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [runapex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_runapex.htm) method of OpenCTI API to send the incoming data and do the search in the Apex Class. If you find a single entry for display, return that Salesforce ObjectID back to your Phone Toolbar to [screenpop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_screenpop.htm). If no single entry found, then use the Apex class to create the appropriate object and send the ID back for Phone Toolbar to screenpop.